# File redirection in Windows and %errorlevel%

Tags: windows, batch-file, error-handling, io-redirection

Lets say we want to create an empty file in windows with the following command:

```
type nul > C:\does\not\exist\file.txt
```

the directory does not exist, so we get the error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

If you print out the `%errorlevel%` the output is:

```
echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Yet the command was not successful!

I noticed, that windows does not set the `%errorlevel%` of the last command if you use redirection..

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
C:\>type nul > C:\does\not\exist\file.txt && echo ok || echo fail
The system cannot find the path specified.
fail

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

I always assumed the && and || operators used ERRORLEVEL, but apparently not.

Very curious that ERRORLEVEL is set after redirection error only if you use the || operator. I never would have guessed. Nor would I ever have bothered to test if not for your excellent question.

If all you want to do is set the ERRORLEVEL upon redirection failure, then of course you can simply do:

```
type nul > C:\does\not\exist\file.txt || rem
```

Comment: @AndriyM - Are you sure ERRORLEVEL was 0 before you started the test? `&& REM` does not "fix" ERRORLEVEL for me on either XP or Vista.

Comment: You are right, it was the `1` set after the test with `||`. After your comment I re-checked and it was `0`. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: A really unexpected behaviour, but perhaps the errorlevel is set by teh exit from the command after setting by the redirections

Comment: @jeb - I don't understand your theory. But I do agree this is very unexpected behavior. I have lots of code that handles redirection errors, but I've always used the `||` operator because I like the compactness. So I never uncovered this odd behavior until this question came up.

Comment: I don't understand what `type nul > C:\does\not\exist\file.txt || rem` is supposed to do. It doesn't change `ERRORLEVEL` for me (Win Server 2012 R2) - it stays the same as set by the last command before redirection.

Comment: @OhadSchneider - I can't speak for Win Server 2012, but on XP, Vista, Win7, and Win 10 `type nul >"bogusPath\test.txt" || rem` will set ERRORLEVEL to 1 if path "bogusPath\" does not exist.

Comment: @dbenham looks like it's only one way though. If the redirection succeeds, the `ERRORLEVEL` stays unchanged (that is it still holds the value set by the last command before redirection) where I would expect it to be set to 0.

Comment: OK I think I undesratnd what's going on. I was using `echo` rather than `type` e.g. `echo nul >"realpath.txt" || rem` and seeing as `echo` keeps `ERRORLEVEL` untouched I didn't see the change.

Comment: @OhadSchneider - It doesn't matter what the command is - if the redirection fails, then the command is never executed. Successful redirection always leaves the ERRORLEVEL alone. Failed redirection only sets ERRORLEVEL to 1 if `||` is used. I can't explain it any better than that.

Comment: @dbenham 10x. The confusing part was that `echo` never touches `ERRORLEVEL` so `echo nul >"realpath.txt" || rem` would leave `ERRORLEVEL` alone (because neither `echo` nor the redirection affect it) whereas `type nul>"realpath.txt" || rem` would set the `ERRORLEVEL` to 0 because `type` sets it to 0 and the redirection leaves it untouched. So to sum up: `cmd > file` will have the `ERRORLEVEL` of `cmd` if redirection was successful and 1 if it was not (regardless of the `ERRORLEVEL` set by `cmd`). In case `cmd` does not set `ERRORLEVEL`, a successful redirection will leave it unchanged as well.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
type nul > C:\does\not\exist\file.txt
```

invoked with a non-existent path is terminated at redirection failure and `type` is not invoked at all. It therefore has no chance of setting `ERRORLEVEL`. The redirection, being performed by the shell, does not set `ERRORLEVEL`.

One solution is to pre-initalise `ERRORLEVEL` with a non-zero value. It will remain unchanged upon failure and will be reset to zero (by `type`) upon success:

```
@echo off
::pre-initialise ERRORLEVEL with a value of 1:
call :SETERROR 1
type NUL > NOSUCHDIR\test.txt
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto ERROR
echo All is well.
goto END
:ERROR
echo Error detected.
:END
goto :eof
:SETERROR
exit /b %1
```

The shorft form

```
type NUL > NOSUCHDIR\test.txt && goto OK || goto ERROR
```

works because it analyses exit code, which is [not the same](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) as error level:

> An exit code can be detected directly with redirection operators (Success/Failure ignoring the `ERRORLEVEL`) this can often be more reliable than trusting the `ERRORLEVEL`, which may or may not have been set correctly.

*Herbert Kleebauer* [explained](http://al.howardknight.net/?ID=157354809800) this to me in the *Usenet* group `alt.msdos.batch`.

**Update:**
An anonymous user suggested an alternative solution based on the `COPY` command:

```
COPY NUL: C:\does\not\exist\file.txt
```

This command does set `ERRORLEVEL`, which may be analysed by the next command in the script. Very convenient, so I thank him for the proposed edit.