# How to detect error when ECHO output redirected to a bad path?

Tags: batch-file

First time posting here.  I'm writing a DOS batch script to automate the process of archiving Oracle tables.  The archive tool requires a parameter file with tags that need to be populated at run-time.  I am using the following logic, trying 2 different methods to catch the error, but when redirecting to a bad path, the error is not being caught.  Is there an alternative to ECHO, or an alternate way to detect this write error?  Or any other ideas?  Thanks much!
-Greg

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%G IN (O:\tmp\infile.txt) DO (
    ...
    ...
   ECHO TABLE=%%G    > P:\BADPATH\MYOUTFILE1.TXT
   IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO END
    ...
   ECHO TABLE=%%G    > P:\BADPATH\MYOUTFILE2.TXT
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO END
    ...
    ...
 )

:END
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO FAILED! 
ECHO EXITING
```

Comment: have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354016/file-redirection-in-windows-and-errorlevel

Comment: Hello wmz, Thanks much for your response.  That is an interesting post.  I need a bit of time to digest it and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but it sounds like you want to check if a file/folder exists first.  If so:

```
IF EXIST P:\BADPATH\ goto notexist else goto exist
:notexist
echo Doesn't exist.
:exist
echo It exists!
```

Or use standard () tags to contain code within.

Comment: Hello.  Thanks much Glenn for your quick response.  That is a great suggestion - I did not know about EXIST.  But I could not understand why ERRORLEVEL works for other commands, but not for ECHO.

Comment: I'm not sure on that one.  Not used errorlevel much, I usually just pre-check for possible errors and act accordingly.  Let me know if it works.