# How to append text to a file besides to "echo.text>>file.txt" command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a problematic part on my batch script

```
echo. Some text >> %file%
if %errorlevel%==0 echo Success!
if not %errorlevel%==0 echo Fail!
```

If `%file%` is somewhere like `c:\windows\test.txt`, that makes the UAC complain

The prompt will display

> ```
> Access Denied
> Success!
> ```

How can I work around this problems that the buffer output doesn't set an errorlevel?
I thought that I may use some command that writes to a text file instead of `>>`.
I can use any command that is built in to Windows above Vista, I can't use other CMD tools.

Any other suggestion is welcome. I just need to append text and check if it was written or not.

Comment: The gist of the question suggests that your issue is same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354016/file-redirection-in-windows-and-errorlevel "File redirection in Windows and %errorlevel%"), even though your title makes it look like something different. Therefore, I'm voting to close your question as a duplicate of the one I've just linked.

Answer (score 1):

This will abort if more permissions are needed, otherwise it will continue.

```
@echo off
set "file=c:\windows\test.txt"
copy "%~f0" "%file%.~~~.tmp.~~~" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 echo no permissions - aborting&goto :EOF
del "%file%.~~~.tmp.~~~"
>>"%file%" echo(Some text
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (echo.something>"%tempfile%a")
ATTRIB +r q21962157.txt

copy q21962157.txt+"%tempfile%a" q21962157.txt >NUL 2>nul
ECHO ERRORLEVEL was %ERRORLEVEL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO error - output text IN "%tempfile%a") ELSE (DEL "%tempfile%*")
ATTRIB -r q21962157.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a method. I used a file named `q21962157.txt` for my testing.

Change the first `attrib` to `+R` for set readonly, `-R` for clear readonly. (I'm just using the readonly attribute to generate an access-denied condition)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you used Powershell instead of Batch, you might expect better integration to the OS.  Perhaps that is why Powershell makes you set Execution Policy before you run scripts.