# How can i run a command when another fails (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to run an Error message if an command fails but i dont know how
I know that you can use `command1 && command2` if you want the second command to be only run if the first was successful but I dont know how to do this in batch. Also the things that i found didnt work like `command1 | command2`.

Im trying this right now `for %%i in (*.osz) do start "" "%%~i | echo Error accrued! && Color c && timeout -1 >nul"` but it dosent work.

Pls Help me

Comment: `|` is for piping output, what you are thinking at is `||` instead.

Comment: as commented above `command && echo success || echo error`. as you only want to test failure `command || (echo your code here)` I put within parens as you may want to do various things

Answer (score 1):

You should look for **"errorlevel"**, you will be able to test **error code returned** by your command : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817833/6424355

```
command
if errorlevel 1 goto errorHandling
goto successHandling
```

In a loop you can call a subpart of your batch by using call :likeAGotoButYouWillGetBackHere

```
for ... call :likeAGotoButYouWillGetBackHere
goto eof
:likeAGotoButYouWillGetBackHere
...
goto eof
```